# Kubernetes backend container only available through REST service

Tags: kubernetes

I am a Kubernetes and sort of Docker newbie. I have an unsecured (no authentication, etc) elasticsearch container (a statefulSet) that is set up with a particular schema. This is a backend service. I have a second container (as a regular pod/Deployment) that contains a REST service which is the only thing that should be communicating with the elasticsearch container.

I understand the basics of Kubernetes pods, deployments, statefulSets, and services used to expose them. Without having to set up authentication for elasticsearch, is there an easy/clever way to configure these two containers so that no other pod’s applications can DIRECTLY utilize the elasticsearch container (only the REST service container)?

I’ve seen the notion of a multi container pod so I was considering making the elasticsearch container a sidecar to the REST service container that communicates for it. But this might be impossible because the ES container is a statefulSet and the other is not?

Is there another way that could involve each being a separate pod?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, create it as a multi-container pod where your REST service will be exposed as a k8s service but will be able to talk to elasticsearch container without exposing it externally.

You can optionally just add your REST container to the statefulSet. statefulSet is essentialy a pod + storage, hence your pod in this statefulSet can be a multi-container pod.

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. How can they restrict _which_ pods can access the service? In this setup any pod can query the Elasticseach API which should be restricted.

Comment: Not true. If you don’t expose ES container, REST service container will be the only one who can talk to ES. Limiting access to the REST service isn’t part of the question?

Comment: [Andy Shinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684908/andy-shinn) could you please explain why do you think networkpolicy can't be used in this case?

Comment: This satisfies the question I asked. After much struggling I got a solution working with ES as a sidecar to the REST service. It is doing what I intended. I am only exposing the REST service in the Service configuration. As for Andy's question about networkpolicy, there may be a better solution with that, I'm just not there yet (Kubernetes newbie :)). I'd be interested in hearing how I could instead use that.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking for network policy that should be in the namespace your pods are deployed. Have a look at the example in [this section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).